# What are the standard ways of deriving and verifying the formulas for integral transforms where the formal formula for the transform diverges?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, integral-transforms, regularization

There are multiple formulas for integral transforms of various functions in the tables of integral transforms, but in many cases the integral, formally representing the transform diverges.
What is the usual way of deriving and verifying those formulas then?

It seems, the current practice is inconsistent: [sometimes the tables give a kind of regularized value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LaplaceTransform%5BExp%5Bx%5D%2Cx%2Ct%5D) without even warning that this is some kind of regularization, while in other cases delta function and its derivatives get involved, etc.